# Can I write annotations in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, annotations

I know I can annotate my classes in Groovy with annotations, but can I write the annotation itself in Groovy (as opposed to just using annotation written in Java)? If so, from what version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define annotations in Groovy.

See more:
 http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_annotation

Comment: Even with the documentation, it took me some trial and error to learn I had to put the definition of the annotation *outside the Groovy class* (same file is fine.)  This differs from Java, where it can be defined inside a class.  I don't know for certain if this is generally true, or perhaps an issue with my Eclipse setup, but it helped me resolve a "Groovy: unexpected token: @ @" error.

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg Looks like a parser bug to me. You could fill a [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5562?jql=text%20~%20%22annotation%20inside%22). I did a quick lookup and didn't found anything related

Comment: The anchor in the link seems to be broken (missing 's' character). Here the new link with the right anchor nowadays.
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_annotations