# Groovy and annotations - what is wrong with this example?

Tags: groovy, annotations

According to [Guillaume Laforge](http://glaforge.free.fr/weblog/index.php?itemid=241), it is possible in Groovy 1.6.1 (and I would presume later versions) to define annotations directly in Groovy. However, I cannot make sense of the simple example below. I try to run this in the 1.7.1 version of the Groovy Console:

```
@Bar
@Foo
class A { }

@interface Bar { }
@interface Foo { }

for(ann in new A().getClass().getAnnotations())
{
    println ann
}
```

When running this example, the console prints

```
@org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.GroovyCompilerVersion(value=1.7.1)
```

and nothing else. What am I doing wrong here?

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791310/can-i-write-annotation-in-groovy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured it out. It had to do with the retention policy, which I foolishly forgot (spending most of my days in C#).

Adding a policy will fix this, e.g.:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Bar { }
```